# Fractional Derivative of Nonlinear Function

Tags: calculus

It is well known that in the case of integer order differentiation holds $\partial_{x}f(x,u(x))=\partial_{u}f \cdot \partial_{x}u+\partial_{x}f\cdot u(x)$. 
If we define fractional derivative via Fourier transform *F* as $D_{x}^{\alpha}u(x)={F}^{-1}[{(i\xi)^{\alpha}\widehat{u}(\xi)}]$, is there a similarly formula for $D_{x}^{\alpha}f(x,u(x))$?

Comment: $ \partial_{x}f(x,u(x))=\partial_{u}f \cdot \partial_{x}u+\partial_{x}f $